# "New to SharePoint" questions

Tags: feature-request

Every now and then, souls that are new to SharePoint pass by this wonderful website and asks the same question - "I'm new to SharePoint, where should I begin?"

Instead of giving them the same answers over and over again couldn't we instead put together a list of books, blogs, and guides which are split into sections of "Newbeginners", "Trained", "Advanced" on a page and have a big fat link on the landing page saying "New to SharePoint? Click here!" ?

Comment: Nice idea, not really sure how we would gather all the content though! It would be nice with a wiki containing links to other relevant questions for beginner for example

Comment: @RobertLindgren I'm imagining we'll gather the content by creating a post asking people to submit what ever materials they seem fit, asking them to post it in a sectioned manner. I'm open for ideas.

Comment: There is a couple of posts already existing, like this one: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72620/where-can-i-learn-sharepoint. How about using this one as a reference? Start to divide some sections that is good to know in the question, and the create answers mapping to the questions below